# ErrorName exception when calling method in __init__

Tags: python-3.x

Ho can I create attributes depending on methods results ?
I'm trying the following code but always get "ErrorName" exception :

```
class Rectangle():
    def __init__(self, height, width):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.area = areaCalc(self)

    def areaCalc(self):
        return self.heigh*self.width
```

Do you know if there is a way to do this ?

Thank you !

PS : 
sorry for my bad english

Comment: you need to call it as `self.areaCalc()`

Comment: May be you need add details such as how are you calling it currently.

Answer (score 0):

`areaCalc` is an attribute of the object in `self` and not a name in the local scope.